# The difference between a scoping annotation and scope instances in Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

In Guice, when you indicate the lifetime of a certain instance, you will use a scoping annotation like `bind(Applebees.class).in(Singleton.class);`.
Or you appear to be able to use scope instances like

```
bind(UserPreferences.class)
      .toProvider(UserPreferencesProvider.class)
      .in(ServletScopes.REQUEST);
```

And officially Guice recommends the former approach because the former approach allows us to reuse the Module class.
But I am not sure of the point.  My assumption is like this, so please check if this is right.

Scope instances is the term of Servelet, so if you adopt scope instances instead of scoping annotations, the Module class is only applicable to the Servelet. On the other hand, if you use scoping annotations, you can reuse your Module class unless you abandon Guice.

So, is this right?  Could you check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your understanding is correct, but there's a little subtlety about what kind of reuse would be affected.

You're probably referring to this text from [the Guice wiki on Scopes](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes#applying-scopes) (emphasis mine):

> The `in()` clause accepts either a scoping annotation like `RequestScoped.class` and also `Scope` instances like `ServletScopes.REQUEST`:
>
> ```
> bind(UserPreferences.class)
>     .toProvider(UserPreferencesProvider.class)
>     .in(ServletScopes.REQUEST);
> ```
>
> The annotation is preferred because it allows the module to be reused in different types of applications. **For example, an `@RequestScoped` object could be scoped to the HTTP request in a web app and to the RPC when it's in an API server.**

Even with Guice's servlet-specific scopes, you can choose between the Scope instance [ServletScopes.REQUEST](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/servlet/ServletScopes.html#REQUEST) and the [@RequestScoped annotation](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/servlet/RequestScoped.html), and choose between `in(Scope scope)` and `in(Class scopeAnnotation)` accordingly (see [ScopedBindingBuilder](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/binder/ScopedBindingBuilder.html)). Nearly every scope should have a corresponding annotation, as they are especially useful on classes and @Provides methods.

It's important to realize here that there's *always* a [Scope instance](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Scope.html) that actually implements the scoping behavior (specifically, wrapping an unscoped Provider so that it can return already-returned instances in the right conditions). To associate an annotation to a Scope instance, you need to make sure that a module calls [`bindScope`](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/AbstractModule.html#bindScope-java.lang.Class-com.google.inject.Scope-), which accepts the Scope annotation class and the Scope instance; for Servlets, [Guice has this binding automatically installed via InternalServletModule](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/extensions/servlet/src/com/google/inject/servlet/InternalServletModule.java#L84).

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
  bindScope(RequestScoped.class, REQUEST);
  bindScope(SessionScoped.class, SESSION);
  // ...
}
```

**So what's the advantage of using `in(Class scopeAnnotation)`?** When binding to a Scope instance, you are telling Guice exactly which Scope instance you want to use, rather than allowing the user an opportunity to use `bindScope` to bind the annotation to a different Scope instance. In the example I bolded above, you can imagine using the same Module without using the actual Guice servlet extensions (other than the annotations), but *this would only be possible if you bind to annotation classes and then call `bindScope` yourself*. If you bind using `in(Scope)`, you'll need to change that line or write a new Module.

This is especially important for your own custom Scope instances and annotations, because it allows you to change your Scoping behavior consistently across your application:

```
@Override public void configure() {
  // BAD: To change the scope, you'll need to change three lines.
  // If you don't change all three together, you'll get inconsistent behavior.
  bind(A.class).to(AImpl.class).in(MyScope.INSTANCE);
  bind(B.class).to(BImpl.class).in(MyScope.INSTANCE);
  bindScope(AScoped.class, MyScope.INSTANCE);
}

@Override public void configure() {
  // GOOD: To change the scope, you can change one line, and optionally
  // extract that line to a separate Module.
  bind(A.class).to(AImpl.class).in(AScoped.class);
  bind(B.class).to(BImpl.class).in(AScoped.class);
  bindScope(AScoped.class, MyScope.INSTANCE);
}
```